# Is await a long time running async function in a request necessary?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

So I have a request like this

```
handleUpdate1 = async(req, res, next) {
  await _asyncFuncWillRun10Minutes(req.body);
  return res.status(200).end();
}
```

So if a client make a GET request to this function, the client will wait around 10 minutes to get the response.

If I change the source to

```
handleUpdate2 =(req, res, next) {
  _asyncFuncWillRun10Minutes(req.body);
  return res.status(200).end();
}
```

The request will return immediately.

My question is the second func `handleUpdate2`, the execution will return immediately, what happens to `_asyncFuncWillRun10Minutes`?

Will it keep running until it finishes normally? Should I use `await` to wait until it finishes normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is the second func handleUpdate2, the execution will return immediately, what happens to _asyncFuncWillRun10Minutes?

Assuming your server is running in a normal environment where your server stays running between requests (not some special server-less environment), then `_asyncFuncWillRun10Minutes` will just run to completion and will finish long after you send the response.

> Will it keep running until it finishes normally? Should I use await to wait until it finishes normally?

Yes, it will keep running until it finishes.  You do not need to use `await` if you do not need to know when it has completed.

BUT...  You must catch rejections from `_asyncFuncWillRun10Minutes` so the bare minimum for your second code block is this:

```
handleUpdate2 =(req, res, next) {
  _asyncFuncWillRun10Minutes(req.body).catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
  });
  return res.status(200).end();
}
```

The downside of not using `await` before sending the response is that client making the request will not have any way of knowing if the asynchronous operation encountered an error.  If that's not a problem for your specific situation, then just catch errors internally and your `handleUpdate2` will work fine.

---

Disclaimer.  There are some run-time environments (often referred to as server-less) that will not keep your code alive after you send a response to the request.  These are specialized hosting environments (usually at a reduced cost) that don't keep your server code running all the time.  Instead, they just handle incoming requests and shut you down as soon as the request is done.   As long as you're not running in one of these specialized environments, your `_asyncFuncWillRun10Minutes` code will continue to run to completion just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `await` in an asynchronous function that makes a request can be necessary in some cases. And it totally depends over the use case. If you need the response of API and make use of it, you need to put an await to stop further execution until you get the response. But if you just want to make an external request and don't need the results, then you can skip the await. It will give you an unresolved Promise and continue further execution without waiting.

When you make an HTTP request using an asynchronous function, the function does not block the execution of the program while waiting for the response from the server. Instead, it returns a Promise object immediately, and the program continues to execute.

Using `await` before the asynchronous function call will pause the execution of the function until the `Promise is resolved`. This is useful when you need to wait for the response from the server before executing the next line of code that depends on that response.

However, in some cases, it may not be necessary to use await. For example, if you don't need to use the response data immediately and can continue executing the rest of the code while waiting for the response, you can simply call the asynchronous function without using await.

In summary, whether or not to use await in an asynchronous function that makes a request depends on your specific use case and whether you need to wait for the response data before continuing with the rest of the code.